# How to get the current labels in a Pod?

Tags: kubernetes

is there a way to get current labels in a Pod?

like this

```
labels := sdk.current.getLabels()
```

I need to initialize my app based on current labels. for example: `app.kubernetes.io/name`

I looked for documentation and some other, but didn't find what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the Go client? If yes, you can fetch the pod and then extract its labels.

```
pod := &corev1.Pod{}
err := k8sClient.Get(context.Background(), client.ObjectKey{Name: "pod-name", Namespace: "namespace"}, pod)
if err != nil {
    // Handle the error
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
}

labels := pod.GetLabels()
```